# Custom Control - Clickable link in properties box

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, windows-forms-designer

I'm making a custom control using C#, and I need to add a link to the property box(so I can show a form once it's clicked).

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: Well, what *kind* of property it is would be helpful.

Comment: add Label or linkLabel and write code on Label's Click event.

Comment: I know this is not the answer - but what I used to do in the past was find an example on a control where that option was available, and then use a tool like JustDecompile to dig into the .NET source code and figure out how to do it.  Sometimes that works....

Comment: @Plutonix It's not really a property, and I think I was pretty clear with that it's a link? Look at the image! Look at where the arrow is pointing at. THAT is what I need!

Comment: @ManuVarghese Umm.... And then how do I add that into the property box?!

Comment: @BrianMains Great idea! Thank you for being the only one with a proper "answer"! :D

Comment: @PaddiM8 make it  Public

Comment: @PaddiM8 You are looking for Designer Verbs.

Comment: @ManuVarghese How would a label magically go into the property box for a certain control just by making it public?! What are you talking about?

Comment: But that link is related to... *a property* It fires up the collection editor for the Items collection *property* - that is after all, the *property designer*.  That is a Verb which is just another way to - not "show a form" but start the associated editor.  its not something you just sprinkle on like a decoration.

Comment: @Plutonix I don't think it's related to a property only. When I went ahead and selected other properties, it was still there.

Comment: Yup - because it is a verb.  Click it and the same *property* collection editor starts up as when you edit the Items Collection property.

Comment: You can use a verb for setting value of a single property, multiple properties or for example for just showing a about box.

Comment: @BrianMains Yes, it's a good idea for OP to look in source code of controls to learn some tricks. By the way, too look in .Net source code, you can use [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) and browse .Net Framework source code online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`DesignerVerb`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.designerverb.aspx).

> A designer verb is a menu command linked to an event handler. Designer
>   verbs are added to a component's shortcut menu at design time. In
>   Visual Studio, each designer verb is also listed, using a LinkLabel,
>   in the Description pane of the Properties window.

You can use a verb for setting value of a single property, multiple properties or for example for just showing an about box.

**Example:**

Create a designer for your control or for your component deriving from [`ControlDesigner`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner(v=vs.110).aspx) class or [`ComponentDesigner`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.componentdesigner(v=vs.110).aspx) (for components) an override [`Verbs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.componentdesigner.verbs(v=vs.110).aspx) property and return a collection of verbs.

Don't forget to add  reference to `System.Design.dll`.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
[Designer(typeof(MyControlDesigner))]
public class MyControl : Control
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
public class MyControlDesigner : ControlDesigner
{
    private void SomeMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Some Message!"); 
    }
    private void SomeOtherMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var p = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this.Control)["SomeProperty"];
        p.SetValue(this.Control, "some value"); /*You can show a form and get value*/
    }
    DesignerVerbCollection verbs;
    public override System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerVerbCollection Verbs
    {
        get
        {
            if (verbs == null)
            {
                verbs = new DesignerVerbCollection();
                verbs.Add(new DesignerVerb("Do something!", SomeMethod));
                verbs.Add(new DesignerVerb("Do something else!", SomeOtherMethod));
            }
            return verbs;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error telling me that it can't cast from ShapeMaker to Control. Btw, the component name is ShapeMaker(and it's a Component).

Comment: Oh wait, let me try ComponentDesigner instead!

Comment: No problem, use component designer.

Comment: Thank you for the help, do you by any chance know how to fix my new problem? The form I want to start needs a variable from "MyControl", but it's started from "MyControlDesigner". So, FormName frm = new FormName(this.Points); won't work! Because MyControlDesigner doesn't have that variable, MyControl does! It's two separate classes...

Comment: `ControlDesigner` has a `Control` property which you can cast it you `YourControl` type and then you can access properties of `YourControl` which you are designing.

Comment: By the way, if you want to edit a `List<Point>` creating a custom form is completely wring idea. There are more standard solutions like this one which I shared. So let me know what's your goal and I'll guide you to the right direction.

Comment: I actually created a form to make a custom shape which will be translated into PointF[]. But now for the loading and saving, I need to access the variable!

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you meant. It's actually a Component(not a normal control). But you mean ControlName.VariableName? ShapeMaker.Points
Because, I've already tried that. It crashed visual studio :P

Comment: And Control.points doesn't work, because it says "Control" has no variable called "points". Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121294/discussion-between-paddim8-and-reza-aghaei).