# How to copy a complex property value from one user control to another as design time?

Tags: c#, winforms, design-time

**TL;DR;**
How can I add copy-paste capability to a complex, multiple values property that will enable me to copy the property value from one user control and paste it to another at design time?

**The long story**

I have created a user control (`StylableControl`) that has a complex property called **`Style`**.

This property contains an instance of a class called `StylableControlStyles`, that contains multiple instances of a class called `Style`, where each one holds values such as `BackColor`, `ForeColor`, `Image`, `Gradient` (another class I've created) etc'.

I've also created a custom control designer to allow editing style property for the user control. It shows a form where each style class in the style property can be edited easily.

Now I want to provide the users of this control an easy way to copy the entire content of the **`Style`** property from one instance of the user control to another instance, at design time.

I could, of course, override the `ToString()` method of the `StylableControlStyles` object to create a string representation that will encapsulate all the data saved in this object, but that would create a hugh string and of course would need a lot of work parsing it in the class converter (currenty I'm just using an `ExpandableObjectConverter`).
I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Are you maybe simply looking for a way to deep clone or deep copy an object hierarchy? If so, there are already [several answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-net-c-specifically) [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects)

Comment: @jcb Actually, the colning part is alreay written, that's not my problem. I'm looking for a way to provide design-time support for copy - paste values between controls on a form. Something like a smart tag command that will enable the user to choose another instance of the user control and copy it's style into the current instance's style.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, if you already have custom control designer form, add Copy Style and Apply Copied Style buttons there, for example. Copied style can be stored in some buffer (maybe even Clipboard. if it is human-readable format, users will be able to insert copied value into .designer.cs file directly)

Comment: @ZoharPeled, alternatively, do you know how DataGridView add some quick access functions in designer (see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmbc6.png)). It is possible to add similar actions (Copy Style..., Apply Style...) to a custom user control

Comment: @Ash That's actually a very good idea. I'll try it. If you could post it as an answer I'll be happy to upvote and accept it if I'll be able to make it work.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I'm sure SO has a good QA which can be used as a duplicate (e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024850/custom-control-clickable-link-in-properties-box))

Comment: @Ash Brilliently simple. I should have thought about it myself. I've used a static variable in the control designer to serve as a buffer. works like a charm, thanks. Sure you don't want a free 25 rep. points bonus?

Comment: If `StylableControlStyles` is marked as `Serializable` (and it's indeed serializable), it *should* work as-is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Ash's advice in the comments I've used a `DesignerVerb` to copy and paste the `Style` to and from a private static member of type `Style` of the control designer.

So in my control designer class I have:

```
private static ZControlStyle _CopiedStyle;
```

And have added these designer verbs:

```
_Verbs.Add(new DesignerVerb("Copy Styles", CopyStyle));
_Verbs.Add(new DesignerVerb("Paste Styles", PasteStyle));
```

And the methods for copy ans paste:

```
private void PasteStyle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_CopiedStyle != null)
    {
        var toggleButton = Control as ZToggleButton;
        if (toggleButton != null)
        {
            toggleButton.Style.FromStyle(_CopiedStyle);
        }
        else
        {
            (Control as ZControl).Style.FromStyle(_CopiedStyle);
        }

    }
}

private void CopyStyle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var toggleButton = Control as ZToggleButton;
    if (toggleButton != null)
    {
        _CopiedStyle = toggleButton.Style;
    }
    else
    {
        _CopiedStyle = (Control as ZControl)?.Style;
    }
}
```