# Custom control editable textbox and context menu functionality like MenuItem

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu, design-time

How can implement the following functionality in my own custom control:

- Substitute one part of my control with a textbox that can be edited in design time (like when you select a menu item twice)
- Add custom menu items to the design time context menu **(Solved)**

[image]

For the context menu user Reza pointed me in the right direction: Using [verbs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.designerverb.aspx#Examples)

```
internal class MyDesigner : ComponentDesigner
{
    DesignerVerbCollection m_Verbs;

    // DesignerVerbCollection is overridden from ComponentDesigner
    public override DesignerVerbCollection Verbs
    {
        get 
        {
            if (m_Verbs == null) 
            {
                // Create and initialize the collection of verbs
                m_Verbs = new DesignerVerbCollection();

                m_Verbs.Add( new DesignerVerb("First Designer Verb", new EventHandler(OnFirstItemSelected)) );
                m_Verbs.Add( new DesignerVerb("Second Designer Verb", new EventHandler(OnSecondItemSelected)) );
            }
            return m_Verbs;
        }
    }
}
```

For the textbox I've toyed around with overriding GetHitTest and then revealing a textbox. But I can't edit it afterwards...

Comment: For custom commands on context menu, you need to customize [Verbs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39025541/3110834) collection of the designer.